# Knockout js nested control flow bindings not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm just starting with Knockout and I'm not sure if I found a bug with the library or if I'm just noobing it up.

I have an array that I want to split between three lists for display purposes but it appears the start and end `ul` tags are messing stuff up for me.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do, it appears that only the first list item is being rendered for each list while the others are skipped.
http://jsfiddle.net/bn44e/2/

Here is a nearly identical jsfiddle where I replace the `<ul></ul>` tags with `<p>start</p>` and `<p>stop</p>` and all the list items are being rendered.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ue4C3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, the opening and closing of ko virtual element binding **must be in the same level of DOM**.

Because what ko managed is DOM, it needs to dynamically create/delete all **DOM (not string)** content inside a virtual element. ko has no way to manage a single `<ul>` (or `</ul>`) String.

So in the first jsfiddle, ko treats your binding like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->

  <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 || $index() === 10 || $index() === 20 -->
    <ul>

    <!-- ignored because there is no matching opening -->
    <!-- /ko --> 

    <li>Index <span data-bind="text: $index()" style="color:blue;"></span></li>

    <!-- ignored because there is no matching closing -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() === 9 || $index() === 19 || $index() === 29 -->

    </ul>
  <!-- /ko --> <!-- this closing actually matches the first opening ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the ignored virtual bindings messed up the binding context for the inner  `<span data-bind="text: $index()"></span>`, have to remove the unmatched virtual bindings to make the internal `$index` working. http://jsfiddle.net/bn44e/1/

I don't know the reason behind the context problem, guess need to dig through knockout source code to find out the impact of unmatched virtual bindings.

But anyway, unmatched virtual bindings should not remain in production code.